# Users are being logged out of web site due to round robin load balancer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, load-balancing

Our operator has implemented a Round Robin load balancer on our web portal and it seems to be causing some problems I can't get to the bottom of.

I'm able to identify which server we're on and as we navigate around the site we stay on server A. If I leave it for 5 minutes and try another page I'll get pushed to server B, logged out and shown the log in page.

I've got them to make sure the MachineKey in the machine.config is the same on both servers and I've tested locally that the session isn't being used - I can turn the session off completely locally and it still works. I've verified on both servers it is creating an ASPXAUTH cookie on the domain so we should be classed as authenticated on both servers - but keep loosing my authentication every time I change server.

Any ideas on what could be causing the logging out? I'm guessing it's my misunderstanding about how ASPXAUTH works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sessions are handled separately from Forms Authentication. There is a good explanation of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335472/does-formsauthentication-setauthcookie-make-a-session-based-cookie/1335538#1335538).

The most common reason for Forms Authentication failures on load-balanced environments is lack of synchronization of the MachineKey element. You've stated that you've got the server operators to ensure that the MachineKey is synchronized, but have you verified this yourself in some way? Is this the case on ALL the web servers? From previous dealings with a couple of commercial web hosts, I've found that it is (unfortunately) difficult to take their assurances at face value.

Another thing to check is if the FormsAuthentication configuration (timeout, path, name, etc.) is the same on all of the hosts.

Are the patch levels the same on all of the hosts? You might want to see if the compatibility switch mentioned [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2659968) is applicable in your situation.

Assuming that the hosting setup is correct, maybe you have initialization code on the page that logs you out if some condition is not fulfilled?

Try to take a look at the server logs and trace the sequence of HTTP requests involved during a failed page request. That might produce a clue.

Edit: This guide to troubleshooting Forms Authentication problems is detailed, and quite helpful: [Troubleshooting Forms Authentication](http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/security-issues/troubleshooting-forms-authentication)

Comment: Thanks, the trouble shooting guide helped me establish that the client is not actually sending the ASPXAUTH cookie when it's requesting the page after the short delay resulting in the server thinking they aren't authenticated. However I'm still struggling to think what the next step is. The fiddler log shows "Tunnel to" "www.mydomain.co.uk:443" both times so why would it not see that as the same URL and pass the cookie in? On both servers the cookie shows the expiry as "At end of session" and is associated with the domain "https://www.mydomain.co.uk"...which in my understanding should work.

Comment: I've marked your answer as accepted because, as you predicted, the web host hadn't fully deployed the MachineKey changes. They had changed it in the Framework folder, but had not changed in the Framework64 folder. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check for any other application functionality which depends on cookies. The web server on Server B will not recognize cookies that came from Server A. If any part of your authentication depends on cookies being populated, then that could cause your problem.

You have probably already ensured that the domain used for cookies is the same on all of the load balanced servers, but I thought I'd mention that. If the domains aren't compatible, then the browser will simply not send cookies to the server.

Comment: My understanding was if Server A and Server B had the same machine key and the same URL then the cookie would be passed between the two. I've just discovered that the cookie isn't being passed when I switch between servers so it looks like for some reason my browser is deciding they aren't the same URL.

Comment: Check two things: with Fiddler or something see if the cookie is being passed at all. If it _is_ being passed, then compare the two machine.config files.

Comment: Yeah it was the machine.configs weren't the same. The host had changed the machine.config's in the framework folder but not the framework64 folder. Thanks for your help